# IntelliJ plugin for modelling events

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Is there an IntelliJ plugin for visualising events (from javax.enterprise.event package)?

It would be nice to have a clickable (as in "open the class") diagram showing where events are created and observed.

Comment: Please check if https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cdi-tool-window.html what you need

Comment: Other than listing your beans, grouped by scope, I really can't see it provides anything. Am I missing something?